# Tor Connection Problem

Tags: mac

I am connected to my university's wifi running on OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 and have downloaded tor, but it has a difficultly connecting to a relay directory. Does this process take a long time or is it possible that I need a bridge to access Tor?

Comment: i have the same problem, after the last update when i launch the tor browser it doesn't connect like before and ask to restart tor, but it quit after few minutes

Answer (score 1):

It *can* take a while to connect to the relay directory, but you may want to setup a bridge to see if that helps. Educational organizations have a history of blocking Tor access so a bridge may be more successful for you.

If you can't use the automated bridge setups in the new TorBrowser, you can:

1. visit https://bridges.torproject.org/ to get a bridge
2. send an email to bridges@bridges.torproject.org with the line "get bridges" by itself in the body of the mail. *This must be done from a GMail, Yahoo, or RiseUp account*

ref: https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges

Comment: Are there specific reasons for universities blocking Tor?  And bridges from the email are less likely to be already blocked.